# $T_{0}-$ and $T_{1}$ axioms.

Tags: general-topology

Good day! I tried to prove some propositions from the separation axioms and I would just like to share it and ask if there are some missing points in my arguments or how can I improve my proof. Thank you.

> Proposition: An arbitrary product of $T_0$-spaces is $T_0$.

Proof:

Let $X=\prod_{i=\Lambda}X_i$, where $X_i$'s are $T_0$-spaces. Let $x,y \in X$, $x=\{x_i\}$ and $y=\{y_i\}$ be distinct points. That is, $x_{ij} \neq y_{ij}$ for at least one index $ij$. Since $X_{ij}$ is a $T_0$-space, there exists an open set $U_{ij} \subset X_{ij}$ and, WLOG, let $x \in U_{ij}$ but $y$ is not. This open subset $U_{ij}$ will give rise to a base on $X$ where $y$ does not belong to. Thus, the result follows.

> Proposition: A set $X$ is a $T_1$-space iff $\forall$ $x \in X$, the singleton set $\{x\}$ 
>   is closed.

Proof:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume $X$ is a $T_1$-space. Take $x, y \in X$. By assumption, $\exists$ a neighborhood of $y$, say $U$ such that $x \notin U$. Notice that $\bigcup_{i \in \Lambda} U_i = X - \{x\}$ is open. Thus, $\{x\}$ is closed.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume the singleton set $\{x\}$ in $X$ is closed. $\forall$ $x,y \in X$, $U=X-\{y\}$ and $V=X-\{x\}$ are open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Hence, $X$ is a $T_1$-space.

Comment: These should really be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

As to the first proof: agreed, in principle. The choice of notation ($ij$ for an index element from $\Lambda$) is somewhat strange, more so as you use $i$ in $x = \{x_i\}$. Just use index set $I$ with indices $i,j$ etc. in it. Then make the base set explicit: $p_{ij}^{-1}[U]$ in your notation.

As to the second: some notation nitpicks: $U_i$ drops out of thin air. I'd say: let $x \in X$. For every $y \in X$ such that $y \neq x$, pick $U_y$ such that $y \in U_y$ and $x \notin U_y$ using $T_1$-ness. Then $X - \{x\} = \cup_{y \in X, y \neq x} U_y$ is open.

Also a slightly different formulation in the second part there: assume that all singleton sets are closed. Then ... etc. Now you seem to be fixing $x$ in the first sentence.

As said, the proofs are essentially OK, but the write-up could be better.